# IE 11 not sending cookies with CORS get request

Tags: cookies, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11, okta

I am making an ajax GET call currently from localhost:8090 with following:

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'https://dev-855592.okta.com/api/v1/sessions/me',
              method: 'GET',

              dataType: 'json',
              xhrFields: {
                   withCredentials: true
              },
              crossDomain: true,
              success : function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              },
              error : function(data){
                console.log('Session not found');
              },
        });
```

As this is an Okta call, it requires cookies to be sent with the request.
But IE 11 is not sending any cookies in the request.

I tried floowing things already:
"Access Data Sources Across Domains : Enabled" in ie11 settings in trusted sites. This solution is working.

But I don't want any impact on end-user and assuming end user has already accepted third party cookies, what should be the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable CORS requests in IE 11, your server must attach the following headers to all responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, SEARCH, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Content-Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control, Location, Lock-Token, If
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: DAV, content-length, Allow
```

Optionally you can also attach the Access-Control-Max-Age header specifying the amount of seconds that the preflight request will be cached, this will reduce the amount of requests:

```
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

You could refer to [this link](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) about implementing CORS for a specific server.